# Unexpected padding/margin in image links

Tags: css, page-flow

Below the main product image here: http://www.ivault.sg/shop/audio/speakers/bowers-wilkins-mm1-speakers
There's a space between the line and the image that's not specified in CSS.

Inspecting element using firefox doesn't show any css paddings/margins that would produce that space too.

Which css property is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a side-effect of the `img` display attribute being set to `inline` (which is the default value).

add a rule to update it to `block`:

```
#image {
    display: block;
}
```

… and it will be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just define in your css

```
a img {
    border: 0 none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This will fix the symptoms, but Eliran Malka has the correct answer.